# Dependency miss match error is throwing while npm install if I use `jsonpscriptsrc-webpack-plugin` npm package with gulp 4.0.2

Tags: npm-install, webpack-4, webpack-plugin

If we try to `npm install` the `jsonpscriptsrc-webpack-plugin` npm package along with gulp 4.0.2 to override the `jsonpScriptSrc` method, we are facing the dependency mismatch issue.

This issue is occurring only if we use the node version 15.0.0 to 15.7.0 and having gulp 4.0.2 in dependency list. For other node versions, it installs the package fine.

[package json details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtsbk.png)

Issue details:

[Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHusu.png)

Replication procedure:

1. Create a package.json file and copy & paste the below code.

```
{
    "name": "wepack",
    "version": "1.1.0",
    "license": "SEE LICENSE IN license",
    "devDependencies": {
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "jsonpscriptsrc-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.0"
    }
}
```

2. Switch the node js version to 15.7.0
3. Try to npm install inside the package.json file location and you will find the mentioned issue.